# Hats list in profile should include each hat's name and description

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, winter-bash-2012

When looking at another user's list of earned hats:<sup>*</sup>

[image: Screen-Cap (Hats)]

only the images of the hats are shown. When I see a hat of which I am envious (want that Waldo hat!), I have to travel to the Winter Bash site and match up the colorful image I just saw with a line drawing to find its name and how to earn it.

It would greatly facilitate my keeping up with the Joneses if the name, and maybe even the criterion, for each hat was displayed in this popup.

<sup>*<sub>Or my own.</sub></sup>

Comment: Which user is that? S/he seems to have a lot of secret hats!

Comment: @Manishearth: It's Aarthi.

Comment: I would say, show the hat name in every place where the hat is shown.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Even better.

Comment: We'll add a tooltip to each hat showing its name and description.

Comment: @Emmett: What's planned? Showing to own profile page or evrywhere?

Comment: @Somnath You'll see it on everyone's profiles.

Comment: @Emmett Now I know how to get the secret hats, and don't feel the urge to do completely random things. This is... probably a sensible idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each hat in the hat popup on the user profile page now has a tooltip showing the hat's name and short description.

No more clicking around randomly in trying to keep up with the <strike>Joneses</strike> Skeets!

Answer (score 7):

Well, the bowtie, spinner, and cupcake hat (not sure about the others) are secret hats. So you're not *supposed* to know how to get 'em.

In addition, there's a way of getting the hat details if you know the name (no, not telling you, but it's rather obvious if you muck around). So I doubt this will be implemented.

---

Ah, you're talking about non-secret hats as well. I see no issue in doing it for those, then :)

Comment: I see the requirements on the Winter Bash site, but I have to click through and try to find the hat's _outline_ just to get its name.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Exactly.

Comment: So I look at a list, see a colorful hat, then I have to go to another page and match that up with a line drawing, and you're saying that's "a way of getting the hat details"? I know how to do that; I'm requesting that it be made easier. Maybe I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Uhhh... No. The bowtie, colorful spinner hat, and cupcake are _secret hats_. Unless you've earned them, there is no way to find them on the winterba.sh main page. Look for the cupcake outline on your page, it's not there.

Comment: I got the secret hat thing, but I'm not actually concerned about those particular hats, I'm talking about learning about _any_ of them. Take the jester hat instead, if you like.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Ah, I see. I see no problem in linkifying those.

Comment: Sorry, mentioning the bowtie was just meant to be a humorous aside. Didn't mean to draw attention to it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: No prob, knowing it exists doesn't make it easier to find.

Comment: Need to change profile pics to align with the hat's positions :P

Comment: @Shahil: I'm a mu. No head required. _Any_ hat looks good on me :P

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to have a way to learn about how to get even the secret hats.  They're hard enough to find out about, and many people will find it harder-yet to get them.

Better to guide people by highlighting the preferred behaviors (as if the badges page didn't do it already).  Lots of people doing semi-insincere actions to try to gain rep and unlock hats would pollute the site, a bit.