# Show hat name when hover on hat in hat list in own user profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, winter-bash-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hats list in profile should include each hat’s name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159172/hats-list-in-profile-should-include-each-hats-name)

Show hat name when hover on hat in hat list at least in user profile. It will be good see hat name rather than going hat list page and matching hat with respective hat.

**At least it should be shown in own user profile.**

[Hats list in profile should include each hat's name and description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159172/hats-list-in-others-profiles-should-include-each-hats-name) request for all user's profile. I am requesting for own user profile. There won't be any secrets by showing in own profile. Because you have that hat.

[image]

Comment: @animuson: It is request for all user profiles.. Why not this request own profile? Will it be duplicate?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk - Both are same. And now he updated the answer to clear your confusion.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: That's a fair point. I assumed that if it was implemented for others' profiles, they wouldn't bother special-casing one's own profile. I've edited to make my request more clearly cover that too.