# Please make hat explanations more discoverable

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hats list in profile should include each hat’s name and description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159172/hats-list-in-profile-should-include-each-hats-name-and-description)

I saw somebody with a hat I didn't recognize (it's not on the list on the Winter Bash site), so I went to his profile, clicked the number in the "hats" link, and saw the pop-up with his hats.  But there was no text and no mouse-over to tell me what the hats were and what they were earned for.  I could go to the Leaderboard, look for the site, and browse through there, but that's a lot more work.  Can we have hat hints in the display on the browser page?

Comment: Yea... I have had this issue... too many steps to get to a hat explanation...

Comment: click this new snowflake icon in the top left, try to follow the links.  turns out i have to go to profile to wear the hat

Comment: @Sam in the Winter Bash main page when you click on hat you gained and "user profile" link there, it will automagically open the hats popup for you.

Comment: @SamIam, but that doesn't help you when looking at someone else's hats.